# How to create Observable for a legacy camera system?

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a legacy camera client to communicate with a camera. The way it works is a bit awkward for the times. Being myself a fan of the "reactive" stuff, I would like to communicate with the camera in a reactive fashion.

## This is how it operates

Whenever you want to start capturing frames, you call **Start** and it begins capturing a frame every 0.5 seconds and you get notified on every frame subscribing to the "on capture" event. The event keeps raising until you call **Stop**.

As such, the camera has:

- a method to **start** capturing frames
- another method to **stop** the capture
- an event that is raised when a new frame is captured

## This is what I want

I would like to encapsulate the camera into a more handy abstraction in which the Start and Stop methods are replaced by an `IObservable<bool>` and the resulting observable should emit batches of captures (`Frames`).

## More details

This is the legacy camera class:

```
class Camera 
{
    void StartRecording();
    void StopRecording();
    public event CaptureEventHandler OnCapture;
    public delegate void CaptureEventHandler(Camera sender, Frame capture);
}
```

**What I want is to create wrap the camera into a class like this** (I've only created the skeleton):

```
public class ObservableCamera 
{
      public ObservableCamera(Camera camera, IObservable<bool> enableCapture)
      { 
          // TODO: Define the 'Captures' observable using the parameters above
      }

      IObservable<Frame[]> Captures { get; }
}
```

The camera should start capture frames when the enableCapture observable emits a `true` and should stop capturing when it pushes `false`.

To clarify it a bit, this is the marble diagram showing the interaction:

- The first sequence is `enableCapture`
- The second should be an auxiliary sequence created from the `OnCapture` event.

[image]

In addition to that, `StopRecording` should be called whenever a **Start** operation was started, also if the `enableCapture` observable terminates or fails.

## So, what do I ask for?

I have received comments saying that my goal isn't clear. To clarify it, this is my question:

**How should I implement the observable to deal with the legacy camera?** I don't ever know how to start.

Comment: So, what is actually holding you back? I fail to see the question.

Comment: The question is implicit since I describe what I want. What's holding me back is ignorance.

Comment: @SuperJMN This might be a good question for Software Engineering exchange if you're asking about the approach to design it. Or are you suspecting there's some builtin thing you need to use but don't know about? (Not a C# dev, so not sure.)

Comment: Although I voted for reopening the question, I think that more clarifications are needed regarding the behavior of the resulting `IObservable<Frame[]> Captures` in case the driving `IObservable<bool> enableCapture` emits duplicate consecutive true's or false's, and in case it completes succesfully or with an error. For example should the `StopRecording()` be called when the `enableCapture` completes?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Big thanks in advance. You're very kind!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I forgot to add that `StopRecording` should be called whenever a Start operation was started, also if the enableCapture observable ends or fails.

Comment: SuperJMN could you edit the question and add this requirement? Also please cast a reopen vote, so that I can post my answer here if possible.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Done!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231067/discussion-between-superjmn-and-theodor-zoulias).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach, that uses the `Window` operator in order to define the windows (periods) when the camera is enabled. The `Camera.OnCapture` event is subscribed at the start of each window, and is unsubscribed at the end of the window.

```
Camera camera;
IObservable<bool> enableCapture;

IObservable<Frame[]> observableCamera = enableCapture
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Publish(published => published
        .Window(published.Where(enabled => enabled), _ => published.Where(enabled => !enabled))
        .Select(w =>
            Observable
                .FromEvent<Camera.CaptureEventHandler, Frame>(
                    h => (sender, capture) => h(capture),
                    h =>
                    {
                        camera.OnCapture += h;
                        camera.StartRecording();
                    },
                    h =>
                    {
                        camera.StopRecording();
                        camera.OnCapture -= h;
                    })
                .TakeUntil(w.LastOrDefaultAsync())
                .ToArray()
        )
        .Concat()
    );
```

The `DistinctUntilChanged` operator is used in order to ignore consecutive true's or false's. The `Publish` operator is used is order to avoid multiple subscriptions to the `enableCapture` sequence. Most probably this sequence will be a `Subject<bool>`, so already hot, making the `Publish` essentially redundant, but it is good to avoid multiple subscriptions in principle.

No care has been taken for the case that either the `StartRecording` or the `StopRecording` method fails. In that case a subscription to the `OnCapture` event will be leaked.

Comment: OK, I don't know what kind of sorcery this is, but I'm absolutely amazed. I think I need to go to the `Publish` and `Window` operators and read carefully. That call to `LastOrDefaultAsync` got me lost! Is there any good way to see what's going on? Any good training/katas for Rx? I really want to master this topic.

Comment: @SuperJMN ha ha! No, I don't know what's the best way to master Rx. And I don't consider a master myself. Every time I want to solve an Rx problem, I am stumbling through all the available built-in operators for hours, searching for the one that can solve the particular problem. Not a very productive way to solve problems, but fun nonetheless. :-)

Comment: @SuperJMN a good learning material is the [Introduction to Rx](http://introtorx.com/) online book, but I'm sure that you know about it.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, there are no complex samples like this one. Real life use cases sometimes require a deep understanding of what's going on. Complex observables (due to the nested composition) are pure craftsmanship stuff. I wish there were katas to practice with.

Comment: Caution, the `Concat` operator [behaves wierdly](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1634) in the current version of the Rx library (5.0.0). My advice is to use the equivalent `Merge(1)` operator instead, until the issue with the `Concat` is fixed. The `1` is the value of the `maxConcurrent` parameter. Setting this parameter to `1` means no concurrency.